# Strange empty string closure of a dfa

Tags: computer-science, finite-automata

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4WrY.jpg

The closure in question is the closure of that final state, I thought it would be the same as the closure of the first state since they both lack a transition out of their respective states on an empty string. What's going on with that final state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is going on. The closure of the final state is the state itself (`q2`), as you thought. The other text in that line describes the transition function for symbol `a` and state `q0` and has nothing to do with the closure, imo.